# What's the difference between http-proxy and ccproxy-http?

Tags: proxy, nmap

Good day,

After execution command `nmap -p 8080 myserver.address` I've got this message

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
```

And aftar `nmap -p 808 myserver.address` I've got

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
808/tcp filtered ccproxy-http
```

What's the difference between those two filter types?

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/q/620448/78897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these ports are acting the same way - by not responding to any network traffic on that port (Filtering). The difference you're seeing is that if there were something listening on that port, it would be expected to be what's listed in the "SERVICE" column. Many HTTP proxies will listen on port 8080 by default. It appears that there's also a piece of software called "CC Proxy" that listens on port 808. This all comes from a database that nmap holds - it's not based on any other software running on your server.

Comment: Hmm, don't quite get this... If the proxy "not responding to any network traffic on that port", then how would NMap even know that there's a service on that port?